# Android live streaming multicast

Tags: android, ffmpeg, streaming, multicast

I have built a Android application based on FFMPEG, reference http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-android-applications-based-on-ffmpeg-by-an-example/. 
Now, I want to live streaming multicast ? 
How to convert multicast to unicast url to live streaming ?
Please suggest.

Comment: http://blog.chromium.org/2013/07/chrome-29-beta-web-audio-and-webrtc-in.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. Another suggest?

Comment: section 5 in this : http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html#the-model-sources-sinks-constraints-and-states